# How to run Bitcoin Core behind corporate proxy?

Tags: bitcoin-core, testnet, bitcoin-qt-setup, proxy

I'm want to run Bitcoin Core client on TestNet and I need to config it for using under corporate proxy.
Since I'm using Squid to set proxy for my system I should set "localhost:3128" somewhere... but **bitcoin-qt** options seems to have only SOCK5 proxy field.

I also tried to set the proxy using the command line:

`./bitcoin-qt --testnet -proxy=localhost:3298`

[image]

...but it doesn't work.

How can I solve? Can I run Bitcoin Core using setting a http proxy?

Comment: Obvious question: is said corporation happy with you running this software on their computers and/or network? If they are, they should be happy to punch the relevant holes through the firewall for you; if they're not, you shouldn't be trying to work around that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bitcoin doesn't use HTTP for its communications - it has its own specific protocol that runs directly on top of TCP.  So an HTTP proxy like squid won't help.

If you aren't able to make outgoing TCP connections through your firewall (mainly to destination port 8333) then you'll have to contact your corporate IT people about adding appropriate firewall rules.  The same if you want to be able to enable listening.

Answer (score 0):

Although `bitcoind` itself only supports socks5, you can make any dynamically linked binary `http-proxy` capable with a `LD_PRELOAD`ing tool like [proxychains](https://github.com/haad/proxychains):

The prerequisite here is that your proxy server itself
supports the `HTTP CONNECT` method to non-standard ports.

In my VM lab setup I  use [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) on `192.168.100.1 8888`  to analyze the network traffic using this `/etc/proxychains.conf`:

```
strict_chain
proxy_dns
remote_dns_subnet 224
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000
localnet 192.168.100.0/255.255.255.0
localnet 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
localnet ::1/128
[ProxyList]
http    192.168.100.1 8888
```

and `bitcoind` using `proxychains`:

```bash
proxychains bitcoind -testnet
```